# Getting strange results trying to divide in ARM

Tags: assembly, arm

I am trying to do division without the divide function in ARM assembly. My code is below. The result keeps being in the 2400's for some reason.

I have tried writing the following pseudocode into arm:
take inputs in r0 and r1
    add r1 to r3 until r3 exceeds r0
    increment counter
    subtract r0 from r3 to get remainder
    printout counter and r3

```
    ldr     r3,=0
    ldr     r6,=0

   next:
    bl      getnum
    mov     r5,r0
    bl      getnum
    mov     r6,r0

    mov     r0,r5
    mov     r1,r6


    bl      mydivide
    b       next






   mydivide:
    cmp     r3,r0
    bge     rem
    add     r3,r3,r1
    add     r6,#1
    b       mydivide




   rem:
    sub     r3,r0
    mov     r2,r3
    mov     r1,r6
    ldr     r0,=output
    bl      kprintf
 output:             .asciz"%dR%d\r\n"
```

Expected: 
? 100
? 40
2R20

Actual:
? 100
? 40
40R2340

Comment: Use a debugger to single step the program and see where it goes wrong. Apparently you use `r6` as a counter but you never initialize it.

Comment: You're using r6 to hold two different values at the same time, both a counter and the divisor.

Comment: I recall fast but complicated divides algorithms for the ARM's that didn't have divide instructions. They used two 256 byte tables, one for quotients < 256, and the other to seed an algorithm to find 1/quotient (sometimes off by +1, so it had to do one final post multiply check).

Comment: @rcgldr: perhaps based on the same radix algorithm that hardware ALU dividers use?  Anything is better than repeated subtraction, for all but the smallest quotients.  e.g. there's a one bit at a time O(log n) algorithm using shifts.  I think it might be the Radix-2 simplest case of what Radix-16 or higher radix HW div/sqrt units do.  And for constant divisors there's of course the multiplicative inverse (getting a compiler to calculate the constants for you is handy)

Comment: @PeterCordes - There was a check for quotient < 256, and if so, use a table. If not, it was a variation of Newton Raphson to get 1/divisor, which doubles the number of bits with each iteration, starting with 7 bits from yet another table. Took 4 multiplies and some adds and shifts to get to 28 bits, then a multiply numerator by divisor, then one more multiply to get remainder and check if the division needed to increment the quotient.